# AFNetworking 2 GET with JSON response

Tags: ios, get, afnetworking-2

I am building a simple GET function that should return a JSON object. Working with AFNetworking 2. The code compiles, but i can not pinpoint the source of the error i get during runtime. 
Could it be that the content-type: on the server is text/html and I expect jsonobj.
The server uses "Basic user:id" header, should I add this to setValue forHttpHeaderField?

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://the website.com"]];
    manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
    [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
    [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"user" password:@"pass"];   
    [manager GET:@"/api/data/interval?month" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@" Yep %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@" Nope %@", error);
    }];
```

And here is the error that I get

```
 Nope Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Request failed: forbidden (403)" UserInfo=0x8a9dec0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://thewebsite.com/api/data/interval?month, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: forbidden (403), NSUnderlyingError=0x8a99e00 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html", AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8bb0ac0> { URL: http://thewebsite.com/api/data/interval?month } { status code: 403, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Language" = "";
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Tue, 04 Feb 2014 13:02:12 GMT";
```

Comment: Check your URL `http://thewebsite.com/api/data/interval?month`

Comment: check your url because error states that, what your are trying to access is forbidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to init your base url.Something like:

```
 NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.abv.bg"];
```

After that you create relative path like:

```
NSString *path = @"/Path/to/somewhere";
```

And finally init URL string like this:

```
NSString *absoluteURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:path relativeToURL:baseURL] absoluteString];
```

And now you can execute request, and you know, that URL is correct:

```
[manager GET:absoluteURL parameters:nil  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@" Yep %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@" Nope %@", error);
}];
```

In your solution you try to execute request to address @"/api/data/interval?month" and not to real URL.
HTH.

Comment: Nice to see more fellow bulgarian iOS Devs here. I went through my code but it worked nice, I found out that there was no need for base64 encoding with the Basic Auth of the server and the method setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername enforces it.